# ASPX: Placeholder not declared

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Actually i'm trying to add another placeholder to my code, in aspx it's look's like the following

```
  <asp:PlaceHolder ID="countPlace" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

While in codebehind i'm trying to do the following

```
  countPlace.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl(footer.ToString))
```

But i'm getting the error `BC30451` which say that countPlace is not declared.

While i'm trying to use countPlace in codebehind i get a warning error which says "change item context"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding `CodeBehind` solved that problem, but actually i can't understand why the other two PlaceHolder was anyway detected without it.

So i just changed from :

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

To:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" CodeBehind="~/Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>
```